# Woocomerce shop page to show category name & display products within that category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a website with Woocommerce plugin installed. I want my shop page to show the category name first & then display the products within that category, then next category name with the products it has.
[image: Screenshot]

already searched in google & here, found a solution, but it is not what I want. it added the category name after the price area of every product. I'm not a pro, so having a difficult time to solve this problem.

```
function wc_category_title_archive_products(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <small class="product_category_title"><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></small>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_category_title_archive_products', 5 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
    $cat_args = array(
        'parent' => '0',
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $categories = get_categories( $cat_args );

    foreach ($categories as $category) { 
        echo $category->cat_name;
        echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="'.$category->cat_name.'" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="DESC"]'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: add this code to /your-child-theme/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

Comment: I can confirm that this is working. So this should be marked as the answer. Thanks @proff.

Comment: Actually the correct path should be /your-child-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
Please note that I have omit the "template" directory. For more information read this.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: If you are interesting read this also
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score 1):

**SHOW PRODUCT CATEGORY NAME ABOVE TITLE IN SHOP PAGE ==> Check on Woocomerce Version 3.5.3  You need to just copy it and paste it to your theme functions.php**

```
function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do a new loop/query for each category. We can automate some of the process by using WordPress's `get_categories` function. Here's an example::

```
<?php    
    $cat_args = array(
        'parent' => '0',
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $categories = get_categories( $cat_args );

    foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>      
        <ul class="product-category">
            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => $category->cat_ID, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                    <!-- Your output -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
    }
?>
```

Comment: but it is not flexible, I have to change my template everytime I add a new category.

Comment: You could always get all of the categories using the [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function. After that, you could do a `foreach` loop through all of them. That would be flexible. If you don't understand, I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes please update it. I'm not very good with php. thanks for all your hard work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you'd want to approach it. It would be anti-productive to post the entire output here. You're going to need to complete the "Your output" section. I hope this helps.